# Can't figure out the regex for something so simple

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a form that's being processed through the POST method in PHP. Some example values being passed are name, age, gender, personality type, etc.

In order to determine whether the user-data that was given is correct, I am using regular expressions.

For example, here's some of the ones that I got to work..
Name (as long as it's not blank, it's fine:

`if (strlen($name) == 0)`
This one worked for me. Another one that worked was the personality type, which had to be of type from the Jung personality test (such as ISTP, ENTP, INFP, etc). My code for that one was:
`if (!preg_match("/[IE]{1}[NS]{1}[FT]{1}[JP]{1}/", $per))` where $per is the Jung personality type the user submitted. This one also worked fine.

The one that I am having difficulty with is the age. It has to be 0-99, so 1 or 2 digits. I feel like it should be something so simple, but for whatever reason it's not working. Here's the REGEX's I have tried:

`/\d{1,2}/`

`/[0-9]{1,2}/`

`/(\d|\d\d)/`

`/([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])/`

I don't understand why none of these would work, all four of them seems like it would match the criteria perfectly. Maybe I'm not understanding how to use regexes properly, but I spent the last couple hours perusing examples so I feel pretty confident that it should be correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT: If this helps at all, passing the value "abcdefg" or "ab" as the $age value comes out as an error (which is correct). But, passing the value of "100", or "333", or "99999", comes out as it matching (which is wrong, or it's not what I want). Hope this helps explain a bit more~

Comment: The first test isn't a regular expression at all.

Comment: They look valid to me, how do you know they aren't work? Post the code that is using them, along with a `var_dump( $the_input_string_you_are_trying_to_match);`

Comment: You're over-using regexes. For the first case, make an array of allowed values and see if it's in that. For the second case cast it to a number and check to see if it's within bounds.

Comment: Also, why on earth are you using regex to constrain the range of numeric input?

Comment: All your regex's should do the job, but to keep it simple, just try a simple `if($age >= 0 && $age < 100)`, this will make it easier to maintain, say for example you want to increase the age to 130 ?

Comment: @WaleedKhan There are any number of permutations of the personality type strings that are allowed, so that is a very inefficient approach. I agree on the second point.

Comment: @nickb the var_dump($age) came out as: string '4444' (length=4)

Comment: The regex all look right so the issue might be in the php function you are using to test the regex. You might want to post that line as well.

Comment: Don't tell me you're using something like this `if(!preg_match('/\d{1,2}/', $age))` ?

Comment: @nickb It would still be partially matched, since there are no anchors. `/\d{1,2}/` matches a string containing any number of digits greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Yeah, I completely understand what everyone's saying. I too, before trying the regex, understood that there's much easier ways. I'm trying to learn webdev and found a nifty course site from last year, and one of the advanced hw options was to use regex instead of regular variable expressions and checks. Thanks for the input guys :)

Comment: @Asad - You are correct

Comment: @hamza that's actually exactly what I'm using lol. If that's wrong, would you mind pointing out why it's wrong?

Comment: REMOVE THE **!** BEFORE PREG_MATCH()

Comment: the "4444" was just a random number I put in as the $age. Since it doesn't match the /\d{1,2}/ criteria, it should come out as not matching, but in my page/code it comes out as it does -___-

Comment: @Isaiah - No, 4444 will match your regexes.

Comment: Okay sorry I was very unclear, I really should have put all this information in my original post. I have an array with all the names such as name, age, gender, and their initial values are all "ok". Then I check them against the regex, and if they're wrong, I change the associated value to "error". Which is why I have to use the ! @HamZaDzCyberDeV

Comment: @IsaiahLee I see, well now that it's solved. You may change the input in your HTML code. Use 'maxlength': `<input type="text" name="age" maxlength="2">`. This will limit the input field to 2 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been said, regex is not the right answer for this. But if you have to use regex, you need start `^` and end `$` anchors. Regex matches part of a string, so `/\d{1,2}/` matches `abc123` because it has at least one number with an optional second number. If you want it to match JUST the 2 characters, you need to anchor the match to the start and end of the string like `/^\d{1,2}$/` to say "start of string, one or two digits, end of string."

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really clears it up. you guys are great :) much appreciated

Comment: Also, if you are doing a lot of regex work, using one of the many online regex expression testers can be helpful:  http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm